# Can the word "pervasive" be used in positive and negative contexts?

Tags: meaning

I see a usage in positive context (Pervasive computing) though the definition is:

> **Pervasive** (adj): (especially of an unwelcome influence or physical effect) spreading widely throughout an area or a group of people.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate:.http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272311/usage-of-prevalent-and-pervasive

Comment: What are positive and negative contexts in which you would use the word? It would be better if you could edit your question with example sentences.

Comment: @Josh61, this question is totally unrelated to the one you refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'pervasive' is itself neutral, so any positive or negative connotations come from whether it is a good thing that is pervasive or a bad thing.

For example 
'Bullying is pervasive in this school' would be negative,
whereas
'Caring for one another is pervasive in this school' would be positive.