# Is it ok to use pervasive in a positive context?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

I read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08887) and something that I am not sure about is:

> Inspired by Pattern Theory [41], we attempt to model three important and **pervasive** patterns in natural signals: sparse discreteness, low dimensional manifold structure and hierarchical composition.

Is `pervasive` an appropriate word here? Isn't it only to be used in negative connotations?

For example: does "**important** and **pervasive**" is a valid conjunction?

Comment: It's worth noting that _important_ can be used to describe positive or negative things; your question seems to imply that you might think it is only for describing positive things... although I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it only used in the negative - no. Is it appropriate here - no, and how sparse discreteness can be pervasive is left as an exercise for the reader. [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272311/usage-of-prevalent-and-pervasive)

Answer (score 4):

You're quite right that *pervasive* is often used when describing the extent of something *negative*. Looking at *pervasive* in [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pervasive):

> **pervasive** *(adjective)*
>
> ***(especially of an unwelcome influence or physical effect)*** 
> **spreading widely throughout an area or a group of people.**

Looking at the first few example sentences in the same [dictionary entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pervasive), let's decide for each if **the thing *pervasive* refers to** is **positive**  , **negative** ☹ , or if it's **hard to say**  **[?]**  :

> ‘**Ageism** is pervasive and entrenched in our society.’ ☹
>
> ‘**Knowledge networks** have become pervasive because they can be simple
>   to implement.’  **[?]**
>
> ‘He exercised a pervasive **influence** on European drama by challenging
>   the conventions of naturalism.’ **[?]**
>
> ‘But it's the pervasive **humour** that wins through, thanks to a nicely
>   crafted script.’
>
> ‘Nevertheless, their **influence** is pervasive within the history of
>   science.’ **[?]**
>
> ‘**It** has become so pervasive that it influences how people write for
>   the Web.’ ☹ **[?]**

It's difficult to determine with sentences in isolation, but, roughly, out of six example sentences, one is definitely positive (and another, the first, very probably is), one is definitely negative (and another, the last, very probably is), and the other two sentences are difficult to classify as either negative or positive.

Not conclusive, it would seem, but that's good enough for us to be able to say:

***Pervasive* is often used with a negative slant (and may carry a presumption of negativity), but is also often used to describe positive effects without any difficulty at all.**

***Pervasive* is fine in your context.**